# Where should I instantiate a location manager if my app uses it throughout its various view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I have an app that uses the user's location throughout its various view conrollers, and I've learned that in order to get that location you need to create a CLLocationManger instance and conform to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.

Is it possible to make one CLLocationManager instance and use it's properties like coordinates in my different view controllers or should I make a CLLocationManager in each view controller class?

Comment: Would it be possible to just create it in a kind of constants file?

Comment: What have you tried already? Yes it is possible and encouraged to use a single instance of a CLLocationManager. The delegate can be a shared object through which other clients can do KVO on its properties or it can send NSNotifications (less ideal)

Comment: @dbn i was thinking about instantiating it in app delegate's didloadwithoptions function and tried referencing the instance from other view controllers but it didn't work. so i came here looking for answers. i just need the latitude and longitude to use in other view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and somewhat robust hack could be:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        return true
     }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        lastLocation = locations.last!
    }
```

In this same source file, at global scope, add:

```
private var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
    didSet { 
        locationCallback?(lastLocation!)
        locationCallback = nil
    }
}

private var locationCallback: ((CLLocation) -> Void)?

func getLastLocation(callback: (CLLocationManager) -> Void) {
    guard let location = lastLocation else {
        locationCallback = callback
        return
     }
     locationCallback(location)
}
```

Finally, elsewhere in your app, you can get your *last* known location using just:

```
getLastLocation { location in
    print(location)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! would that be better than creating a singleton/static class and doing kind of the same thing there?

Comment: @PaulJohn I would say yes, samething as singleton! BUT if your app gets huge, with all kinds of location-based features, then refactoring this code to a dedicated class is the way forward ;-)